# Construct a hypothesis test

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

From a manufacturing process, $n = 25$ items are manufactured. Let $X$ be the number of defectives found in the lot. Construct a $\alpha = 0.01$ level test to see if the proportions of defectives is greater than $10$%. What are your assumptions?

My attempted answer is :

We need at least $3$ defectives in order for the proportion of defectives to be greater than $10$%

($p$ is the proportion of defectives)

$H_0$ : $p \leq 0.1$

$H_1 : p \geq 0.1$

I will reject $H_0$ if $X > 3$

Specifically, I don't understand how alpha will affect the answer

Comment: Hint: $X$ follows the binomial distribution

Comment: Where a bound $3$ of critical region comes from? For this region, $\alpha$-level is significantly greater than $0.01$: for $X\sim Bin(25, 0.1)$, $P(X>3)\approx 0.236408642446827$ (Excel).